# Normative reference for Posix regex class definitions?

Tags: regex, posix

At http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html (which looks sort of like an official specification for Posix) it lists the character classes which must be supported in regular expressions, including e.g. `[:space:]`.

But where are those character classes defined? Where can I find definitively which characters `[:space:]` should match? I'm looking for an actual standard, not a wiki-like-page-thing or somebody's blog.

Answer (score 0):

This set is locale dependent.

The POSIX one is detailed here: 
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap07.html

> **space**
>   Define characters to be classified as white-space characters.
>   In the POSIX locale, exactly <space>, <form-feed>, <newline>, <carriage-return>, <tab>, and <vertical-tab> shall be included.
>
> In a locale definition file, no character specified for the keywords upper, lower, alpha, digit, graph, or xdigit shall be specified. The <space>, <form-feed>, <newline>, <carriage-return>, <tab>, and <vertical-tab> of the portable character set, and any characters included in the class blank are automatically included in this class.

In addition the the previously mentioned characters, locales are free to add any number of horizontal or vertical "space" characters, like for example "non breaking space", "fixed width space" and similar.

To know if a given character is part of this class or not in the current locale, you use the [isspace](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/isspace.html) function.